# Meteor can't find local npm module

Tags: meteor, npm, package, importerror

I am developing some npm packages parallel to my Meteor application.

The first one is finished and it's tests and build are running without errors.

I want to install my package (`mypackage`) in my meteor project (`myproject`) by using a local path:

```sh
cd myproject
meteor npm install --save ../lib/mypackage
```

Note, that it exists in a `lib` folder outside of the Meteor project. This seems to install the package, as it outputs

```sh
+ mypackage@0.0.1
added 1 package in 12.475s
```

When looking into the node_modules folder it also exists, but it only as a (soft?) link:

```sh
cd node_modules && ls -la | grep mypackage
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  group     22 26 Jan 11:02 mypackage -> ../../lib/mypackage
```

Here comes the problem: When running my project or my tests I get an error for the following line:

```js
import { SomeClass } from 'mypackage';
```

The error is:

```sh
W20180126-11:07:08.933(1)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'mypackage'
W20180126-11:07:08.933(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
W20180126-11:07:08.933(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
W20180126-11:07:08.933(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/meteor-test-runqigr0c.jhjdg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:287:32)
W20180126-11:07:08.934(1)? (STDERR)     at makeInstallerOptions.fallback (packages/modules-runtime.js:651:18)
W20180126-11:07:08.934(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:16)
W20180126-11:07:08.934(1)? (STDERR)     at collections.tests.js (imports/startup/both/collections.tests.js:1:306)
W20180126-11:07:08.935(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180126-11:07:08.935(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180126-11:07:08.935(1)? (STDERR)     at /private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/meteor-test-runqigr0c.jhjdg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:7933:1
W20180126-11:07:08.935(1)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/meteor-test-runqigr0c.jhjdg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)
```

I tried to resolve this using absolute paths but it did not help. Has somebody experience with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special npm feature for doing this called `npm link`

It allows you to use your local package in preference over the published version. You will first need to an `npm link` inside the source of the package itself (to make it available)

And then within your project you do it again, but naming the package, eg `npm link my-package`

More information here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked with `mui-rte` npm package, I needed to make some changes so forked it and try to install locally. Here are steps to make it works.

1. Go to `mui-rte` local folder, run `npm run build`
2. Inside `mui-rte` folder, run `npm link`
3. Go to the project folder, run `npm link mui-rte`

It works. Thanks @Mikkel for the link. @Jankapunkt I'm using Meteor too.